# How to recognize user inputted websites as link tags using HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

If the user inputs any of the following:

- http://www.foo.com
- www.example.org
- fooexample.gov/images/foo.jpg

then the script should automatically make the output recognize these as links

practically every email service do this and most professional dynamic sites as well, so I'm wondering how this is coded.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a demo for your question, in here: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/9dqbf9fr/4/

Actually the key is replacing the url string by regExp like below:

```
$('textarea').change(function() {
    var tmp = $(this).val();
    var url_reg = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*/g;

    var result = tmp.replace(url_reg, function(link) {
        return '<a href="' + link + '">'+ link +'</a>';
    });       

    $('p').text(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- first, you should attach an event to the input controller, like keyUp, keyDown or Input in jquery.
- second, using regular expressions to find out that the value in controller is the url or email format.
- at last, dynamic replace the input values by wrapping a  element